# Octopus Nuget Push error: IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection:

Tags: octopus-deploy, octopack

I am using Bamboo as build server and Octopus deploy for Deployment. I am using their command line tool, Octo.exe to create and push nuget packages to the server.
It was working fine. But we started getting errors which were intermittent at first and then became very common. Now it fails almost everytime but succeeds once in a while. I have installed the Server and tentacle in the same machine.

This is the error I am getting

```
Handshaking with Octopus server: http://Server/
17-May-2016 19:51:11    Handshake successful. Octopus version: 3.3.12; API version: 3.0.0
17-May-2016 19:51:11    Authenticated as: ajaybhasy <> 
17-May-2016 19:51:11    Pushing package: C:\build\WOR-WA-JOB1\client\dist\WorldSmartAngular.1.0.337.nupkg...
17-May-2016 19:53:39    System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
17-May-2016 19:53:39       at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.MultipleSend(BufferOffsetSize[] buffers, SocketFlags socketFlags)
17-May-2016 19:53:39       at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.MultipleWrite(BufferOffsetSize[] buffers)
17-May-2016 19:53:39       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

According to the posts in their support I tried changing the Tentacle to polling mode, but that too didnt work for me.

Comment: They have a default [30MB package limit](http://help.octopusdeploy.com/discussions/problems/184-30mb-default-maximum-nuget-package-size), may be you were at the edge of it before and went over it?

Comment: Are there any errors in the `OctopusServer.log` file in the octopus directory?

Comment: @RobertWagner The error shown in Octopus is Unhandled exception from web server: Bytes to be written to the stream exceed the Content-Length bytes size specified.